# Are the DMO COM interfaces supported in Windows Store apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, dmo

Are the DirectX Media Object COM interfaces supported in Windows Store apps? I can't seem to find anything that says either way on MSDN. I'm thinking of interfaces like [IMediaObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) etc.

Comment: I suppose that would be Media Foundation only, that is no `IMediaObject`, just `IMFTransform`. I have no confirmation for this, just a guess coming out of announced API availability there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a [list of supported Win32 and COM APIs in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452756.aspx)  and DMO is not on it.